# OpenOffice upgrade to 4.1.2 - Command Line with Macro No Longer Working

Tags: macros, openoffice.org, freeze, openoffice-basic

We've been using OpenOffice Portable to convert .docx files to PDFs.

We run a command like the following in a .NET MVC web application running as NETWORK SERVICE.

```
.\soffice.exe -invisible macro:///ConversionLibrary.PDFConversion.ConvertWordToPDF(sourceFile,destinationFile)
```

That was working without issue using OpenOffice Portable version 3.2.

We tried upgrading to OpenOffice 4.2.1, installed the macro and verified that the macro runs correctly when I run it in a command line as a normal user.   However, when NETWORK SERVICE tries to run it from the web app, it spawns up a soffice.exe*32 and an soffice.bin*32 and just hangs for several minutes until it times out.

I verified that NETWORK SERVICE has write access to the destination directory, read access to the source file, and again I verified that I can run the command manually in a command window.

I haven't seen anything in our logs or in the system log to tell me what's going on.  I'm not really sure where to go from here.  Does anyone have an insights that could help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Check `Tools -> Options  -> OpenOffice -> Security` and click the button that says `Macro Security`.  If that is not the problem, then I would try to debug the macro by adding logging statements that write to a text file.  That would show if the macro is running at all, and if so, where it is getting stuck.

Answer (score 1):

FYI - turned out you can add a .ini file in the root folder called "OpenOfficePortable.ini" and turn off the splash screen with DisableSplashScreen=true This fixed the problem